# Laravel how to use if condition for array data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.4 where I want that if I choose array element like dashboard and profile it active the "actives" class instead of this it return "inactives" class.

```
   <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 sidebar-main" >
    <a class="anchor" href="{{BASE_URL}}dashboard">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 sidebar-inside {{ collect(request()->segments())->last()==$menus ? 'actives' : 'inactives' }}" >
      <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12  sidebar-section"  >
        <p class="img-center" ><img class="sidebar-images" src="{{ asset('images/agent/User-Name.png') }}" > </p>
        <p class="engs">Main screen</p>
        <p class="arbs" style="">القائمة الرئيسية</p>
      </div>
      </div>
      </a>
```

I am a newbie in laravel and my question is: How can I pass the array data for the if condition or how can I solve this problem or how can I take the laravel `request()->segments())->last()` in a variable so I could use that variable instead of this line.

Comment: Keep this data into controller function variable and send that variable in blade view.

Comment: How can i can u pls update the question with answer ??

Comment: @sweta Try `( request()->segment(count(request()->segments())) == $menus ? 'actives' : 'inactives' )` condition.

Comment: no i am asking about how to get value in blade and use that value in view..@Chonchol Mahmud

Comment: You should first read laravel documentation. Read this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#passing-data-to-views hope you will find your answer.